# How to close all running applications at once (not background processes)?

Tags: gnome, kde

How to close all running applications at once?

Is there a solution with a graphical user interface?

Is there any addon?

Please suggest one for both GNOME and KDE Plasma.

In windows 10:

[image]

Applications are categorized separately from background processes.

[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349858/how-to-close-all-applications-in-a-workspace ;-)

Comment: If you're not running Wayland and have wmctrl installed you can run a command like `kill $(wmctrl -lp | grep -v "\-1" | awk '{print $3}')` that will grab all open apps that have a window and close them at once.  This does not close background apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can install DashToDock extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/, then you will have a "Quit all" feature per application when doing a right click on opened Windows. I'm afraid that CloseAll like app doesn't exist on Gnome or Kde. Sorry, I'm not sure if KDE has a similar feature.

[image]

Comment: that will kill many background apps as well. i want only the ones that are active and running. individual selecting these apps is not what i want. i dont want to kill background apps.

Comment: Okay, my answer updated as well, hope this will answer your question ;-)